# CodeIgniter funciona em Linux?

Tags: php, codeigniter, framework

Estou iniciando com o Framework CodeIgniter e queria saber de vocês se ele funciona em hospedagem linux normal ou irei ter que contratar um dedicado?

Comment: Sim funciona em linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frameworks em PHP independem da plataforma que seu servidor está rodando, eles só dependem da versão do PHP instalada! Antes de instalar o CodeIgniter verifique se ele suporta a versão do PHP instalada no servidor.